# Pagination in PHP MySQL not limiting data and neither going to next page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have listing in my HTML which is displayed from database. My listing code is like below:

```
<?php

require('admin/db_config.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM image_gallery";
$images = $mysqli->query($sql);

while($image = $images->fetch_assoc()){

?>



  <div class="aamir"><span><img style="height:40px; width:55px; " class="img-responsive" alt="" src="admin/uploads/<?php echo $image['image'] ?>" /></span><small><?php echo $image['title']; ?></small><strong style="width:40%; height: 35%;"><em  class="icon icon-chevron-down"></em><p style="margin-top: -5%;"> <?php echo $image['description']; ?> </p></strong>
    <a
      class="zayan" target="_blank" href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">VISIT</a>
  </div>

  <?php } ?>
```

Now I have given pagination for the same because the data is too much and I want it to go to next page. So I have given pagination. Pagination code is below:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_GET['pageno'])) {
        $pageno = $_GET['pageno'];
    } else {
        $pageno = 1;
    }
    $no_of_records_per_page = 10;
    $offset = ($pageno-1) * $no_of_records_per_page;

    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sample");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        die();
    }

    $total_pages_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM image_gallery";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$total_pages_sql);
    $total_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)[0];
    $total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $no_of_records_per_page);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM image_gallery LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page";
    $res_data = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_data)){
        //here goes the data
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="?pageno=1">First</a></li>
    <li class="<?php if($pageno <= 1){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
      <a href="<?php if($pageno <= 1){ echo '#'; } else { echo " ?pageno=".($pageno - 1); } ?>">Prev</a>
    </li>
    <li class="<?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
      <a href="<?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo '#'; } else { echo " ?pageno=".($pageno + 1); } ?>">Next</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="?pageno=<?php echo $total_pages; ?>">Last</a></li>
  </ul>
```

But still the pagination is not working, no error is shown, the whole data is being displayed in one page and the pagination is like static.

Comment: Just to check - your first listing is the old version and the second is the new version (and replaces the old one).

Comment: @NigelRen i didnt understand what you said

Comment: what type of pagination do you want? share the output that you want to so that we can understand your issue better